# SQL Server decimal data type performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a few tables that store quite large numbers, so I've chosen `decimal(17, 2)` as the data type for all the columns.

Example of schema:
Table1 (value1, value2, value3, value4, value5)
Table2 (value1, value2, value3, value4, value5)

For argument sake, if I have 100,000 rows in each table, and each value is `100.00`, how will the query performance be compared to if the data type was `decimal(5, 2)`? Will it be negligible? Will the main difference be the storage space taken up?

Comment: What query? And why don't you just try it out?

Comment: there are so many dependancies -- maybe you should try building some test tables with both data types and executing the same queries on both tables, and see what the results are.

Comment: `float` can hold larger values than `decimal`.

Comment: A `decimal(17,2)` will take up 9 bytes.  a `decimal(5,2)` will take up 5.  So the storage difference with 2 tables, 4 columns, and 50,000 rows will be 1.6MB.

Comment: For 100k rows.. does the performance gain really outweigh the accuracy lost with float? I choose accuracy over small perf gain any day. Stay away from floats as much as you can.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Decimal type strictly because you are working with 'quite large numbers' then you are using the Decimal type for the wrong reason. The decimal type is used when rounding accuracy is the major concern, not because the numbers are large. Actually, for really large numbers, a **float** would be a better choice, since it can hold larger numbers. As far as performance is concerned, your best bet is to simply test it for yourself. Fill a table with 100,000 rows of decimals, floats reals etc. and test query performance.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. It's financial data so I'm using decimal for good reason.

Comment: You are using DECIMAL(17,2) for financial data? Are you calculating gross national debt?

Comment: @f470071 ... For argument's sake... normal inflation is 3% ... abnormal inflation is greater. Think about the developers in the 70's that gave us the Y2K nonsense and how many digits they thought *they* would need to represent financial data...hmm? Oh, and non-USD currencies? Hmm? Lots of reasons to think harder about a question like that.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN decimal and numeric](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)

```
Precision    Storage bytes
--------------------------
1 - 9        5
10-19        9
```

So, It `decimal(5, 2)` takes 45% less than `decimal(17, 2)` in the storage.

The difference in execution time **depends on the tasks and configuration of your server**. If the bottleneck is the load on the I / O system and then increase likely will be ~40%.